# Are small categories large?

Tags: category-theory

*Mac Lane* works in *CWM* with a **universe** $U$. It has certain properties,
and one of them is that $U$ is transitive. All sets belonging to
$U$ are **small sets** and subsets of $U$ are **classes**. Classes that
are not small sets are **proper classes**. Now I quote (from pg 22):

---

*'...a
category is small if the set of its arrows and the set of its objects
are both small sets;'*

---

Secondly I quote (from pg 23)

---

*'A large category
is one in which both the set of objects and the set of arrows are
classes (proper or otherwise).'*

---

The word 'otherwise' here gives me
the impression that every **small category** is also a **large category**.
The transitivity of $U$ implies that small sets - as elements of $U$ - are also subsets of $U$, i.e. classes (that are not proper). Is my interpretation correct? If so
then I wonder: are there any categories that are not large? If the answer
is 'no' then what is the use of giving every category the label 'large'?

Comment: You're thoughts are correct. He probably calls them "large" just to emphasize, that they are maybe not small. In many situations in category theory is it fundamental, whether the category you're working with is small oder not and many things won't work with categories, that are not small. So "large" means intuitively "be careful".

Comment: I think better terminology would be "potentially large"

Comment: Are finite sets countable? Sometimes they are, sometimes they aren't...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably Mac Lane meant large category for not necessarily small, meaning that small category are large categories too. So I think your interpretation is correct.

Anyway based [on this very reliable source](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/large+category) it seems that's not universally accepted if by large category one should mean a category which is not small or a category which *could* (but does't have to) be small.

About the necessity of the term large category, the same Mac Lane explain that there are some *categories* which aren't large: for instance the category of classes and function between them. This isn't a large category because the collection of the objects isn't a class (neither a proper one), for the Cantor's theorem for classes.